# replacement has x# rows, data has x# aggregate R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a list of data.frames, `mrns[[i]]`, and want to create a new variable for each one, `mrns[[i]]$avg.hr.prhr`, which is average heart rate per hour.

My code and error:

```
for (i in 1:310) {
  mrns[[i]]$avg.hr.prhr <- aggregate(raw.Hour ~ raw.HR, data=mrns[[i]], mean)
}

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "avg.hr.prhr", value = list(raw.HR = c(46L,  : 
  replacement has 32 rows, data has 93
```

I tried to use `data.table` as well and was getting the same error and I also created an empty variable before running the loop as well with:

```
for (i in 1:310) {
  mrns[[i]]$avg.hr.prhr <- ""
}
```

I also checked the rows for each variable in a couple of the data.frames and they seem to be the same number of rows.

```
length(mrns[[1]]$raw.HR)
[1] 93
length(mrns[[1]]$raw.Hour)
[1] 93
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit**

Tried to use ave instead of aggregate:

```
for (i in 1:310) {
  mrns[[i]]$avg.hr.prhr <- ave(raw.HR ~ raw.Hour , mrns[[i]], FUN=mean)
}

Error in rep(value, length.out = nrows) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'language'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In split.default(x, g) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable
2: In split.default(seq_along(x), f, drop = drop, ...) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable

for (i in 1:310) {
  mrns[[i]]$avg.hr.prhr <- ave(raw.HR, raw.Hour, mrns[[i]])
}

Error in interaction(...) : object 'raw.Hour' not found
```

The thing with the is that I know raw.Hour is not an object, it's just a variable name

```
names(mrns[[i]])
 [1] "raw.Number"         "raw.Reading_Status" "raw.Month"          "raw.Day"           
 [5] "raw.Year"           "raw.Hour"           "raw.Minute"         "raw.Systolic"      
 [9] "raw.Diastolic"      "raw.MAP"            "raw.PP"             "raw.HR"            
[13] "raw.Event_Code"     "raw.Edit_Status"    "raw.Diary_Activity" "na.strings"        
[17] "raw.facility"       "raw.lastname"       "raw.firstname"      "raw.id"            
[21] "raw.hookup"         "raw.datetime"       "raw.mrn"            "unis"              
[25] "ar.value"           "ar.cat"             "baseline.visit"     "visit.date.1"      
[29] "total.sleep.time"   "ID"
```

Comment: The duplicate values of `raw.HR` are being aggregated. You might be looking for `?ave`

Comment: Ah, good call. I used ave instead of aggregate and got `Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors`

Comment: Added the FUN option to ave for that previous error, edited question.

Comment: Thanks @PierreLafortune. I am now getting `Error in interaction(...) : object 'raw.Hour' not found`

Comment: Right. Wrap it in `with(mrns[[i]], ave(raw.HR, raw.Hour))`. Btw this would all be a lot easier if you provided some sample data from `mrns`

Comment: So perfect. Thank you for your continued help! I'll remember to provide sample data next time. Thanks again @PierreLafortune!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i in 1:310) {
  mrns[[i]]$avg.hr.prhr <- with(mrns[[i]], ave(raw.HR, raw.Hour))
}
```

Thanks to @PierreLafortune.

Comment: You're welcome. And as you get better with functions, try to use helpers like `lapply`. In this case `lapply(mrns, function(x) with(x, ave(raw.HR, raw.Hour)))`

Answer (score 0):

What about `lapply` and `dplyr`?

```
    library(dplyr)
    new_list <- lapply(mrns, function(i) { 
         i %>% group_by(raw.Hour) %>% 
         mutate(avg.hr.prhr = mean(raw.HR)) %>% 
         ungroup()
   })
```